# ListViewByQuery fails to show document context menu

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I have created web part that uses the ListViewByQuery control which is linked to a Document Library. The documents are displayed and all is good.

However, when hovering over the document title to get the context menu (for versioning etc) a message box appears when clicked saying the document no longer exists.

Currently the code really is as simple as:

and

```
SPList list = web.Lists[new Guid("XXX")];
SPView view = list.Views[new Guid("XXX")];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery(list.Views[new Guid("XXX")]);
query.ViewFields = fieldList;
this.filteredList.List = list;
this.filteredList.Query = query;
```

Any ideas? Pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code, I am not having any such problem

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                SPWeb currentWeb = site.OpenWeb();

                SPWeb rootWeb = site.RootWeb;
                ListViewByQuery CustomersListViewByQuery = new ListViewByQuery();
                // create the toolbar, actually we cannot hide it, we'll need to extend the webpart and those options
                SPList list = rootWeb.Lists[ListName];
                rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                string jobNumber = FilterColumn;
                string title = currentWeb.Title;

                CustomersListViewByQuery.List = list;
                string query = null;
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    query = @"<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='" + jobNumber + "' /><Value Type='Text'>" + title.ToString() + "</Value></BeginsWith></Where>";
                }
                else
                {
                    // apply filtering and/or sorting
                }
                SPQuery qry = new SPQuery(list.DefaultView);
                qry.Query = query;
                CustomersListViewByQuery..Query = qry;

                this.Controls.Add(CustomersListViewByQuery);

                rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

            }
```